# PhpStorm, docblock with object shape

Tags: php, autocomplete, phpstorm, docblocks

I want to define object shape for autocompletion in PhpStorm.

for example:

```
$myobject = json_decode("{id:1, price:123.99}");
```

for arrays exists docblock:

```
/**
 * @var array{id: int, price: float}
 */
$myArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

and when I type:

```
$myArray['']
```

IDE autocompletes it to `id` | `price`

I want to do it in a similar way for objects:

```
/**
 * @var object|stdClass{id: int, price: float}
 */
$myObject = json_decode($jsonString, false);
```

and get autocomplete when I type

```
$myObject->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not supported by PhpStorm yet as fas as I'm aware.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-66396 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress. Once implemented it will be coming as a part of Psalm plugin.